# Different performance in RStudio and local R shiny session

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, shiny

I'm writing a simple R Shiny app to visualize some data. The approach I'm currently using is to load all data in the beginning, and then allow the user to filter it using controls. The data is considerable in size (12M rows by 6 columns) but there is more than enough free memory on the local machine where I'm doing all the testing (4GB free vs 0.5GB size of the data set).

The part that is puzzling me is that filtering data seems almost as slow as loading the entire data set. This line below takes about 11 seconds to complete:

`dataToPlot = global$data %>% filter(TIME > t1 & TIME < t2 & SUBCI==input$selectSubci & METRIC_NAME %in% input$selectMetricNames)`

Even more suprising is that running the equivalent code takes less than a second in an interactive RStudio session.

I'm not sure what to do next -- there are some profiling tools available, but I guess there's little point in doing that since I know (from print statements) the specific line that takes all the time? Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Nikolai

Comment: Shiny is a fat complex  beast on top of everything, so it's hard to help out without a reproducible example. You could profile your program (Rstudio includes a handy tool for that) that could perhaps help you drill down to the bedrock of the problem. You could try another way of filtering, too. Overengineered approach would be to dump everything in an sql database.

Comment: One alternative you could try is to use `data.table` instead of `dplyr` for a data set of this size, maybe this could already help

Comment: Sticking with the `print()`, you could also try to divide the filter into smaller parts, i.e. `TIME > t1`, save the data, then on this data `TIME < t2` etc., maybe that would say something about what part is the slowest. However, the fact that the difference in `shiny` and interactive session is so big is very interesting, but I don't know what may be a reason.

Comment: how consistent is the time of 11 seconds to calculate ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs, I decided to change the approach altogether and load data as needed with user inputs' plugged into the database query. Works relatively well so far.